# Is there a way to have @url.Action on an <img> tag

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a  tag and I'm using Razor syntax. Im using the @url.Action html helper to pass a parameter to a method on a controller to retrieve the picture. But I want to have this picture as a link so when the user click the picture it would go to the controller and open a different view. So I tried the both ways show below but it's telling me that it's missing a "}" for "Tryone". And for "Trytwo" its not giving me any errors but it does not show me the picture as a link.  Any ideas of the wright way to do this?

tryone

```
@foreach (var p in Model)
{   
     <a href= "@Url.Action("Index","Home")>           
    <img width="50" height="50"
          src= "@Url.Action("GetImage", "Sells", new {p.ItemID })" />
     </a>                                        
}
```

trytwo

```
@foreach (var p in Model)
{                    
    <img href="@Url.Action("Index","Home")" width="50" height="50"
          src= "@Url.Action("GetImage", "Sells", new {p.ItemID })" />                                                 
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An issue with your first attempt is that the `href` attribute is missing a closing quotation mark before the ending angle brace.

```
@foreach (var p in Model)
{   
     <a href= "@Url.Action("Index","Home")">           
    <img width="50" height="50"
          src= "@Url.Action("GetImage", "Sells", new {p.ItemID })" />
     </a>                                        
}
```

Comment: This works, however in some cases, the call is returning an exception. How would you suggest handling this?

Answer (score 2):

trytwo is not working because `img` does not support `href` attribute.

Use your first approach with correct syntax - add quote (") at the end of `href` value.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you extend `HtmlHelper`.

Something like this:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{

    public static MvcHtmlString ActionImageLink(this HtmlHelper helper, string controller, string action, object parameters, object linkHtmlAttributes, string src, object imageHtmlAttributes)
    {
        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
        var url = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(controller) ? action : urlHelper.Action(action, controller, parameters);

        var imgTagBuilder = new TagBuilder("img");
        var imgUrl = urlHelper.Content(src);

        imgTagBuilder.MergeAttribute("src", imgUrl);

        if (imageHtmlAttributes != null)
        {
            var props = imageHtmlAttributes.GetType().GetProperties();
            props.ToList().ForEach(prop => { imgTagBuilder.MergeAttribute(
                prop.Name,
                imageHtmlAttributes.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(imageHtmlAttributes, null) as String);
            });
        }

        var image = imgTagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);

        var aTagBuilder = new TagBuilder("a");

        aTagBuilder.MergeAttribute("href", url);

        if (linkHtmlAttributes != null)
        {
            var props = linkHtmlAttributes.GetType().GetProperties();
            props.ToList().ForEach(prop =>
            {
                aTagBuilder.MergeAttribute(
                    prop.Name,
                    linkHtmlAttributes.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(linkHtmlAttributes, null) as String);
            });
        }

        aTagBuilder.InnerHtml = image;

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(aTagBuilder.ToString());
    }}
```

Then you can use it in your cshtml page:

```
@Html.ActionImageLink("Controller", "action/url", null, null, Url.Content("image/location"), null)
```

remember to create a reference to your extension class.

References:

Extending HtmlHelpers:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/720515/Custom-HTML-Helper-for-MVC-Application

Extension Methods:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer. Im using mvc3 and when I try to use @Html.AcationImageLInk it does not show. Is this an overwriten html helper or this is your own created html helper ?

Comment: It does not exists by default.  The solution that I have presented is an extension method to HtmlHelper.  You will have to create it in your code base somewhere.  After you create it you will have to reference the class you create.  In my case, I create a namespace called @using Web.Mvc.Custom;

Comment: Also I'm using 4.5.1 framework.  you may have to modify this a little bit for 3.0.